# React-Native music player. Not loading songs correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm making a music player in React-Native. The music is being stored locally and I'm also using an Audio Visualizer to display the songs. The songs are not being loaded correctly but they still play. The first song won't load, but when skipping the song they play correctly. Regardless of whether the song is playing or not the Audio Visualizer doesn't load.

I want the player to display the songs properly as well as a visualizer that matches with the song.

```
    import {View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, 
    Text} from 'react-native';
    import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo- 
    router';
    import { AudioControls, AudioVisualization, 
    Song, SongList, StatusBar, Playlist} from 
    '../components';
    import Songs from '../components/AllSongs';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
    const Home = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [selectedSong, setSelectedSong] = 
    useState(null);
    const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);
    
    const handleSongPress = async (song) => {
        setSelectedSong(song);
        if (sound) {
            await sound.unloadAsync();
            setSound(null);
        }
    };

    const handleAudioPress = async (action) => 
    {
        try {
          if (!sound) {
            const { sound: newSound } = await 
    Audio.Sound.createAsync(
              selectedSong.audio
            );
            setSound(newSound);
            await newSound.playAsync();
          } else {
            switch (action) {
              case "play":
                await sound.playAsync();
                break;
              case "pause":
                await sound.pauseAsync();
                break;
              case "previous":
                await sound.unloadAsync();
                const previousIndex =
                  Songs.findIndex((song) => 
     song.key === selectedSong.key) - 1;
                const previousSong =
                  Songs[previousIndex >= 0 ? 
     previousIndex : Songs.length - 1];
                setSelectedSong(previousSong);
                const { sound: previousSound } 
     = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
                  previousSong.audio
                );
                setSound(previousSound);
                await 
     previousSound.playAsync();
                break;
              case "next":
                await sound.unloadAsync();
                const nextIndex =
                  Songs.findIndex((song) => 
     song.key === selectedSong.key) + 1;
                const nextSong =
                  Songs[nextIndex <= 
     Songs.length - 1 ? nextIndex : 0];
                setSelectedSong(nextSong);
                const { sound: nextSound } = 
     await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
                  nextSong.audio
                );
                setSound(nextSound);
                await nextSound.playAsync();
                break;
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        }
      };
    const handleSkipNext = async () => {
     try {
        if (sound) {
            await sound.unloadAsync();
        }
        const nextIndex = 
    Songs.findIndex((song) => song.key === 
    selectedSong.key) + 1;
        const nextSong = Songs[nextIndex <= 
    Songs.length - 1 ? nextIndex : 0];
        setSelectedSong(nextSong);
        const { sound: nextSound } = await 
    Audio.Sound.createAsync(nextSong.audio);
        setSound(nextSound);
        await nextSound.playAsync();
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }
    };
    return (
        <SafeAreaView
        style={{
            flex: 1,
        }}>
        <ScrollView 
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View>
                {selectedSong ? (
                    <>
                    <Song 
                    title={selectedSong.title}
                    artist= 
    {selectedSong.artist}
                    album={selectedSong.album}
                    duration= 
    {selectedSong.duration}
                    audio={selectedSong.audio}
                    image= 
    {selectedSong.image}/>
                <AudioControls 
                audio={selectedSong.audio} 
                onAudioPress={handleAudioPress}
                sound={sound}
                onSkipNext={handleSkipNext} />
                <AudioVisualization audioRef= 
    {sound}/>
                </> ) 
                 : (
                    <SongList songs={Songs} 
     onSongPress={handleSongPress}/>
                )}
               
                
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
     }

    export default Home;



 import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 
 'react';
    import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react- 
 native';
    import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';
    
    
    const AudioVisualization = ({ audioRef }) 
 => {
        const canvasRef = useRef(null);
      
        useEffect(() => {
          const canvas = canvasRef.current;
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          const analyser = 
 audioRef?.current?.context.createAnalyser();
          const source = 
 audioRef?.current?.getMediaElementSource();
      
          if (analyser && source) {
            source.connect(analyser);
           analyser.connect(audioRef.current.context.destination);
          }
      
          const render = () => {
            const width = canvas.width;
            const height = canvas.height;
            const frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser?.frequencyBinCount || 0);
            analyser?.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF';
            const barWidth = (width / frequencyData.length) * 2.5;
            let x = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < frequencyData.length; i++) {
              const barHeight = (frequencyData[i] / 255) * height * 0.7;
              ctx.fillRect(x, height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
              x += barWidth + 1;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
          };
      
          render();
        }, [audioRef, canvasRef]);
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: 200, height: 100 }}/>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    });
    
    export default AudioVisualization;

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import Slider from "@react-native-community/slider";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const AudioControls = ({
  audio,
  onAudioPress,
  onSkipNext,
  sound,
  setSound,
}) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [playbackPosition, setPlaybackPosition] = useState(0);
  const [playbackDuration, setPlaybackDuration] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initSound = async () => {
      if (sound) {
        await sound.unloadAsync();
      }

      const { sound: newSound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(audio);
      setSound(newSound);
      setIsPlaying(true);
    };

    initSound();
  }, [audio]);

  const handleAudioPress = async (action) => {
    switch (action) {
      case "play":
        await sound.playAsync();
        setIsPlaying(true);
        setSelectedSong((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isPlaying: true, sound: sound })); // Add sound object to state
        break;
      case "pause":
        await sound.pauseAsync();
        setIsPlaying(false);
        setSelectedSong((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isPlaying: false})); // Add sound object to state
        break;
      case "previous":
        // handle previous track
        break;
      case "next":
        onSkipNext();
        setIsPlaying(true);
        setSelectedSong((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isPlaying: true})); // Add sound object to state
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const handlePlaybackStatusUpdate = (playbackStatus) => {
    if (playbackStatus.isLoaded) {
      setPlaybackPosition(playbackStatus.positionMillis);
      setPlaybackDuration(playbackStatus.durationMillis);
      setIsPlaying(playbackStatus.isPlaying);
    } else {
      setPlaybackPosition(0);
      setPlaybackDuration(null);
      setIsPlaying(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSliderValueChange = async (value) => {
    if (sound) {
      await sound.setPositionAsync(value);
      setPlaybackPosition(value);
    }
  };

  const handleSliderSlidingComplete = async (value) => {
    if (sound) {
      await sound.setPositionAsync(value);
      setIsPlaying(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;

    const getPlaybackStatus = async () => {
      if (sound && isPlaying) {
        const status = await sound.getStatusAsync();
        handlePlaybackStatusUpdate(status);
      }
    };

    interval = setInterval(getPlaybackStatus, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [sound, isPlaying]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleAudioPress(isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")}
      >
        <FontAwesome
          name={isPlaying ? "pause" : "play"}
          size={32}
          color="white"
          style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Slider
        style={styles.slider}
        minimumValue={0}
        maximumValue={playbackDuration || 0}
        value={playbackPosition}
        minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
        maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        onValueChange={handleSliderValueChange}
        onSlidingComplete={handleSliderSlidingComplete}
        disabled={!sound}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAudioPress("next")}>
        <FontAwesome
          name="step-forward"
          size={32}
          color="white"
          style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  slider: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
});

export default AudioControls;
```

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: In your given code, when you open the app, `selectedSong` is `null`. Which means `audioRef` in `AudioVisualization` is also `null`. It is not the error but it blocks the visualization from working normally until you select the song and start to play. To handle this, render only when `audioRef` is truthy, update the code: `const AudioVisualization = ({audioRef})=> `  add the following  `useEffec(()=>{ if (!audioRef) { return; }`